# Issue with ViewPager in application

Tags: android, view

I know we can flip pages horizontally using ViewPager.But is there any function which i can override which can catch the action when i will flip pages left and right.I mean any function which will be called when i will flip left and any function which will be called when i will flip right.Anyone having any idea please share. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the page transition by calling `setOnPageChangeListener()` and specifying your own `OnPageChangeListener`.

Comment: I know there is a function.But how can i detect that page is flipping left or right ? any idea?

Comment: The `onPageSelected()` method of your `OnPageChangeListener` implementation will be called with an `int` argument which represents the index of the new page. By comparing this to the index of the current page you can work the direction of the flip.